# Strange Hens and a half

Tags: mathematics

If a hen and a half lays an egg and a half in day and a half, how many eggs will six hens lay in nine days?

Comment: Half a hen can't lay an egg- dead hen. Half an egg would an awful mess.

Comment: “If one and a half chickens lay one and a half eggs in one and a half days, how many eggs will nine chickens lay in nine days?” - Isaac Asimov, Escape, *I, Robot*. Look familiar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming there's no "gotchas!" with things like how half an egg could be laid etc. the answer is:

> 36 eggs

Reasoning:

> If 1.5 hens lay 1.5 eggs in 1.5 days, then 1 hen will lay 1 egg in 1.5 days. 9 days is 6x1.5 day periods, so the 6 hens will each lay 6 eggs, for a total of 36 eggs.

Answer (score 3):

> x hens lay y eggs in z days.
>
> x hens lay $y\times\dfrac{9}{z}$ eggs in 9 days.
>
> 6 hens lay $\dfrac{6}{x}\times y\times\dfrac{9}{z}$ eggs in 9 days.
>
> In this case $x=y=z=\dfrac32$, so:
>
> $$6\cdot\frac23\times\frac32\times9\cdot\frac23=4\times\frac32\times6=36\,\text{eggs}$$

Comment: I eggspected for eggsample the half a hen would be eggspired t*hen* it shell lay duck eggs.

Comment: $\pi$ hens lay $e$ eggs in $\phi$ days...

Answer (score 2):

They will lay:

> 36 eggs

Because:

> ```
> Hens   Eggs   Time
> 1.5    1.5    1.5
> 6      6      1.5
> 6      36     9
> ```